# WCF How to change soap request method name .NET Core API

Tags: xml, .net-core, soap, asp.net-core-webapi

I created classes automatically from a WSDL using the Visual Studio 2022 editor. I am trying to ensure that the method name does not appear in the request XML structure when I call the method using Soap UI.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v3="http://belediye.turkiye.gov.tr/v3">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v3:sicilSorgula> ---->> This is method name and I want to remove this element
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v3:sicilSorgulamaG>
         </v3:sicilSorgulamaG>
      </v3:sicilSorgula>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
```

but that didn't work

Request XML structure must be like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v3="http://belediye.turkiye.gov.tr/v3">
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v3:sicilSorgulamaG>
            <!--Optional:-->
         </v3:sicilSorgulamaG>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Then you have to modify the c# classes.  The code may not work when you get done since the xml has a schema and you will get errors if the xml does not match the schema.

Comment: when I use base wsdl and test it soapui <v3:sicilSorgula> is not found in request xml

Comment: Is it in the c# classes?  Did you add a value to object in the class?

Comment: You define a [MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)] for the input parameter, you also need to define a separate parameter for the output, I recommend you to check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/unwrapped-messages) and refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733486/how-do-i-remove-the-method-node-from-the-response).

Comment: I decided to write the project with .net web application instead of .net core. In .net web aplication **[SoapDocumentMethod(Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]** property solved the problem. I used the same wsdl in both project. At the same time, there was a problem in binding input parameters to classes in the .net core project.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.Services` is a predecessor of WCF. Since even the mighty WCF is considered deprecated on the server side, do not expect `System.Web.Services` to be available in .NET Core or the concrete App Model ASP.NET Core 1.0. Their namespaces even start with Microsoft.AspNetCore. SOAP is considered deprecated in favor of REST and JSON. Microsoft will tell you: Use the **.NET Framework** but not **.NET Core**.